# Seeking Reporting tools

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting

We are looking for a web-based reporting tool solution. Either freeware or commercial would be considered. The requirement is that the web UI would allow user to select various options, and run them against database, which returns data to UI to render a report. Ideally, it should support various popular document format. The reporting tool should support high volume of queries, and produce good performance.

The architecture and system we are using are below:
SQL Server 2008
.NET 4
AJAX-based Web UI

Any idea would be very much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited to either SuperUser or Programmers?

Answer (score 2):

You could do a lot worse than looking at SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) the version that comes with 2008 is good, the version that ships with 2008R2 is better and the upcoming project crescent looks amazing!

The reports that are generated can be displayed in a number of ways. The simplest way is simple URL web reports however there are a number of other options such as the report viewer control that you can use in winform and webform applications. You can also integrate them into a sharepoint library if you need to.

And the best part is if you have SQL server it is free!

Answer (score 1):

Based on second hand recommendation, I'd suggest looking seriously at http://www.tableausoftware.com/.  A lot of products have excellent looking feature lists.  But I know someone whose opinion I really trust who has introduced a number of clients to that one and has good things to report about the experience.

But there are a ton of companies that have solutions to sell you.  You should definitely look around.  But, and this is a big but, don't buy into anything based on the sales pitch and the feature list.  Instead try to get your technical people talking to technical people at clients who use the software.  Try to get honest feedback.  Everyone has slick presentations, but most don't really deliver.